# How can I use an integer in different voids?

Tags: c#

I am writing some code in C# (Winforms .network). I get the error that `pos` does not exist in the current context. I understand the error, but I don't know how I can fix this. The error is in this part of the code:

```
if (j == x && i + pos == y)
{
   label.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Timers;

namespace TetrisBlok
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Label label;
        
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

        }
        
        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int[,] matrix = {
                        {0, 1, 0},
                        {0, 1, 0},
                        {0, 1, 1}};
           
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
                {
                    label = new Label();
                    label.AutoSize = false;
                    label.Name = "label" + j.ToString() + i.ToString();
                    label.TabIndex = 0;
                    label.Text = "[" + j.ToString() + "]" + "[" + i.ToString() + "]";
                    label.Visible = true;
                    this.Controls.Add(label);
                    label.Location = new Point(Size.Width / 2 - (5 - i) * 50, Size.Height / 2 - (11 - j) * 30);
                    label.Size = new Size(50, 30);
                    label.BackColor = Color.White;
                    if (i % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        label.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                    }

                    
                    int w = matrix.GetLength(0);
                    int h = matrix.GetLength(1);

                    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
                    {
                        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
                        {
                            if (matrix[x, y].Equals(1))
                            {
                                if (j == x && i + pos == y)
                                {
                                    label.BackColor = Color.Red;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            int pos = 0;
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                pos = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error because I make `int pos` in the `Form1_KeyDown`. What must I change so I can use the `int pos` in the `Form1_Load` and the `Form_KeyDown`?
I want that whenever I press the right arrow key, `int pos` will increase by `1`. Then I want to use that value in the `Form1_Load` so I can move something.

Comment: If I'm feeling mean then I'd suggest you use Reactive Extensions to represent your key-presses [as an observable stream of events](https://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html) - but for now, just define an _instance field_ in your `Form1` class to pass data between methods (or rather: to _share state_ between method invocations).

Comment: you can put `int pos` as property of `Form1` (`public partial class Form1 : Form { int pos;...`). however, keep in mind `Form1_Load` runs only once (when the `Form` is loaded).

Comment: @Dai how must I do that?

Comment: Remove 'int' from 'int pos = 0;'  put 'private int pos = 0;'  under 'private Label label;' its not the best way but as you are learning its fine.

Comment: @BagusTesa, you're right it runs only once. What do you recommend to use if I want to move something? Because when I don't put it in anything the positioning of my 10×20 field go wrong